# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CicekListesi'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When the page is first loaded, I can bind the dropdownlist, but when the page is post back I get this error:

> There is no ViewData item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key 'CicekListesi'.

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UrunEkleCicek() 
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    ViewData["CicekListesi"] = new SelectList(db.CicekTuru, "cicekID", "cicekAdi");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UrunEkleCicek(Urun UrunBilgi)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // ...

    return View();
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UrunEkleCicek","EkleCikart", FormMethod.Post ,new{enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    @Html.DropDownList("CicekListesi", null, "Çiçek türü seçin", new { @class = "form-control"})*@

    <input type="submit" value="Ürünü Ekle" class="btn btn-success" />

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: By setting `ViewData["CicekListesi"]`  in your POST action method again.

Comment: It means that the value of `CicekListesi` is `null` because you did not reassign the `SelectList` in the POST method before you return the view. Same as [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o), but a different message because you use `DropDownList()` rather than the preferred `DropDownListFor()`

Comment: @CodeCaster i am new with mvc. Can you write with code ? :)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC isn't WebForms, MVC holds no state of your page whatsoever.

You're already properly setting the dropdown's data in the GET action method:

```
ViewData["CicekListesi"] = new SelectList(db.CicekTuru, "cicekID", "cicekAdi");
```

Well, "properly", you'd rather use a view model for this, but the above works as well.

Now when you POST this data and there's something wrong, you apparently want to display the form again. The form then needs the `SelectList` data again to properly display.

So simply repeat the above code in the POST action method as well.